# Как использовать random.choice со списками в Python?

Tags: python

```
import random

a =  "the", "at", "to", "of"
n =  "cat", "dog", "girl", "boy"
v =  "sang", "ran", "jumped", "danced"
ad = "loudly", "quietly", "well", "badly"

for a1, n1, v1, ad1 in range(x):
    a1 = random.choice(a)
    n1 = random.choice(n)
    v1 = random.choice(v)
    ad1 = random.choice(ad)

print (a1, n1, v1, ad1)
```

Как потом сделать пять циклов и при помощи функции `random.choice()` 
выбрать артикль, существительное, глагол и наречие?

У меня выходит только с первой строкой. Не могу понять, как повторить пять раз.

Comment: у вас код ломается, не доходя до `random.choice()`. Если не можете самостоятельно это исправить, то задайте отдельный вопрос (специально об TypeError, который вы получаете. Тело цикла (после `range(x):`) можете просто на `pass` в этом случае заменить--это не влияет на возникновение ошибки)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы сделать что-то пять раз в Питоне, можно цикл по range(5) использовать:

```
result = [[random.choice(L) for L in [a, n, v, ad]]
          for _ in range(5)]
```